# Proving that the boundary set of $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x+e^y<z^2\}$ is $\partial  = \{ (x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 ∶ x + e^y = z^2 \}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Consider metric space $\Bbb R^3$ with usual distance $d$. Let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x+e^y<z^2\}$. Prove that the boundary set $\partial A=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x+e^y=z^2\}$

First of all, I denoted $B=\{ (, , ) \in \Bbb R^3 ∶  + ^ = ^2 \}$.
Then I am able to show that $\partial \subseteq B$ by showing there exists an element in the boundary set which is a solution of the equation.

However, I got stuck on showing the reverse direction.
Can I say the distance between every element in $B$ with $A$ is $0$ so that there exist $2$ convergence sequences (one is a subset of $A$ and the other is the subset of the complement of $A$) both converge to an arbitrary point in $B$. Thus, $A$ is a subset of $B$. I am confused about the construction of such two sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b\in B$. Note that $B\cap A=\emptyset$ so the sequence $c_n\equiv b$ is a sequence converging to $b$ in the complement.
To show there exists a sequence in $A$ converging to $b$, denote $b=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and set $d_n=(x_0-1/n,y_0,z_0)$ then clearly $\forall n:d_n\in A$ while $d_n\to b$.

Comment: Sorry but what exactly do you mean by Cn≡b, is it the sequence contains only points in B?

Comment: I meant the constant sequence $b$